# Bootstrap pagination not reflecting in the table on deleting the rows

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap table with pagination and a delete button at each row. In this table I have 10 row each page. If I click on Delete button at page 1, the data of next page should appear at first page, which is not happening with my code. Below are my HTML and Javascript files that I have tried.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="body">
        <div class="content">
            <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>S.N.</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php 
                $sn = 1;
                foreach ($rows as $result) {
                    ?>
                    <tr id=<?= $result['address_id'];?>>
                        <td><? echo $sn++; ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $result['Name'] ?></td>
                        <td><? echo $result['Address'] ?></td>
                        <td>
                            <?php echo delete_btn('delete.php?id=',$result['address_id']); ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#example').DataTable();
        $('.dataTables_length').hide();
        $('#example tbody').on('click', '.btn-danger', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            var row = $(this).closest('tr');
            var id = row.attr('id');
            $.alert({
                title: 'Alert!',
                content: 'Are you sure you want to delete data?',
                buttons: {
                    Yes: function() {
                        $.post('delete.php',{'address_id':id},function(data){
                            if(data.success==true){
                            setTimeout(function() {
                                var siblings = row.siblings();
                                row.remove();
                                siblings.each(function(index) {
                                    $(this).children().first().text(index+1);
                                });
                            }, 100);
                        }
                    },'json');
                    },
                    No: function() {
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: most likely your call to delete.php is failing and therefore won't remove the row.

Comment: @Forbs where should I make changes then?

Comment: in the `if (data.success==true)` area add another `alert ('This was success!');`, that way you can see if the delete.php call is working

Comment: yes that is working